# Yii - Css - One active effect for multiple link

Tags: php, css, yii

I have a main menu bar, the items is: Emlpoyees, Work, Search...(My project power by Yii)

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Home'), 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Employees'), 'url'=>array('/hr/index')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Work'), 'url'=>array('/work/index')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','About'), 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Contact'), 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),

            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Search'), 'url'=>array('/hr/search')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','User Access'), 'url'=>array('/rights'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name==='admin'),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Manager User'), 'url'=>array('/user'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name==='admin'),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Login'), 'url'=>array('/user/login'),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Logout').' ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/user/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
    ))); ?>

</div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

Yii set a "active" on the , it working when I go to link, ex: index.php?r=hr/index, "Hr" will active (change background-color).

```
 #mainmenu ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul li.active a
    {
       color: #FF6633;
       background-color:#fff;   
       border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

But I want the background-color in "Hr" change when I go to link index.php?r=hr/create, index.php?r=hr/manager, ... Help me please!
(Sorry, my English is bad :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items of a CMenu also have an `active` field (boolean), which determines which menu items should be rendered as active. (Have the appropriate CSS class.)

By default, this `active` field is evaluated to `true`, when both the current controller and action are matching, but you can easily override this with a custom expression to only consider the current controller:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Home'), 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Employees'), 'url'=>array('/hr/index'),
                  'active'=>Yii::app()->controller->id=='hr'),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Work'), 'url'=>array('/work/index')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','About'), 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Contact'), 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),

            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Search'), 'url'=>array('/hr/search')),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','User Access'), 'url'=>array('/rights'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name==='admin'),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Manager User'), 'url'=>array('/user'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name==='admin'),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Login'), 'url'=>array('/user/login'),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','Logout').' ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/user/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
    ))); ?>

</div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

Comment: Thanks you to your answer, it's good. Now cant you help me fix this problem:
- "Search" (link hr/search) is have controller->id==hr, so "Employees" was active.
- "User Access" and "Manager User" is "rights" and "user" extensions, it's 2 modules, and it's not work in this case.

Comment: @ÂuZu you can fetch the `id` of the currently active module through `Yii::app()->controller->module->id`

Comment: Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Then the controller does not belong to any module.

Comment: Thanks you, I saw 'baseUrl' in config file, and I try with controller->module->baseUrl=='/rights' and it work.

Comment: Now I have new problems: I added 'id' to 'rights' and 'user' on config file. It word well when I go to <host>/rights or <host>/user. But when I go to <host>/hr, <host>/work (hr and work ís not a modules), and controller does not mean controller->module->id and it error.

Comment: I try: 'active'=>isset(Yii::app()->controller->module) ? Yii::app()->controller->module->id=='rights' : false, and it's good. Thanks for support :D